# Ordered of pairs 2 sets

Tags: problem-solving

Suppose there are two sets, A={a,b,c} and B={x,y}
All ordered pairs in form of (element of A, element of B)
All ordered pairs in form of (element of B, element of A)

Comment: This is not even a question....

Comment: So, what have you tried? Also, please see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A\times B = \{(a,x),(b,x),(c,x),(a,y),(b,y),(c,y)\}$$

$$B\times A= \{(x,a),(x,b),(x,c),(y,a),(y,b),(y,c)\}$$